# Milnor's definition of index of a vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I have a question concerning Milnor's book: **Topology from the differentiable viewpoint**.

First (p.32), he defines the *index of $v$ at an isolated zero $z$*, where $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $v: U \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is a smooth map:

[image]

Then (p.34), he defines the *index of $w$ at an isolated zero $z$*, where $M$ is a smooth manifold and $w: M \to TM$ is a smooth vector field on $M$ (using local charts):

[image]

What I do not understand is the following: technically, his map $dg^{-1} \circ w \circ g$ goes from $U$ to $TU$ (where the tangent bundle $TU$ of $U$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$), so I do not understand this definition.

My first idea was the following: $TU$ is trivial, so actually, the set $\mathfrak{X}(U)$ of vector fields on $U$ is in bijection with the set $\mathcal{C}^1(U,\mathbb{R}^m)$ (let $\Phi$ be such a bijection). Thus, coming back to Milnor's definition, I would say that given a vector field $w: M \to TM$ on $M$, the *index of $w$ at an isolated zero $z$* should be the index of $\Phi[dg^{-1} \circ w \circ g]$. So:

- either this is what Milnor means, but in that case, I do not see why this definition does not depends on $\Phi$,
- or this is not what he means, and in that case, I do not understand at all his definition.

Thanks for you help !

Comment: The tangent bundle to an open set of $\mathbb{R}^m$ is trivial. The isomorphism $T_xU\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ assumed is the one obtained by sending the basis $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_x\}$ (coming from the standard coordinates on $U$) to the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: @andres1 Thank you for your answer. I don't understand... Yes, $TU$ is trivial, so it is diffeomorphic to $U \times \mathbb{R}^m$, right (denote it $f$) ? We can obtain a map from $U$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ by composing next with the projection, but how do you know which map $f$ is used here on the definition ?

Comment: I've told you isomorphisms $f_x:T_xU\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$, now the isomorphism $TU\rightarrow U\times\mathbb{R}^m$ is just $(x,v)\mapsto(x,f_x(v))$.